# Is calling AsQueryable<T> on a DbSet<T> "safe"?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Say I want to unit test Entity Framework's query logic, one way would be to convert the `DbSet<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` before building the expression trees for easy mocking. Is this "safe" and is there anything to be aware about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not only safe, it is legal and fully standard. This is what OO is all about. You just downcast. A `DbSet` HAS to be a `IQUeryable`, per the contract defined by the designers.

Comment: Regarding the downcast, looking at the 5.0 documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.103).aspx (couldn't find a 6.0 version), DbSet does not seem to inherit from IQueryable, that's why it seems a little fishy to me.

Comment: @JohnNevermore Look at the generic version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Silly me, totally missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with `AsQueryable()`. If one of your variable is of type `IQueryable<IEntity>` after calling `AsQueryable()`, **you don't know anymore what the concrete type of the variable is** (`DbSet<IEntity>` in your example).

While **it's perfectly valid from an OOP perspective** (that's the whole point of the interfaces !), it can lead to a lot of bugs/mistakes. Remember that until you enumerate a `DbSet<IEntity>` source, you don't actually execute the query.

That's why for example you can't join an in-memory `IQueryable<IEntity>` (for example `new List<IEntity>{ ... }.AsQueryable()`) with the result of a `DbSet<IEntity>` using `.Union(...)`...